# Unity timer issue

Tags: c#, timer, unity-game-engine

I'll explain what I'm trying to do first of all.

I have an object with a material attached to it. From my camera I have a ray being projected and when it collides with my object I'm wanting the material of that object to be placed onto another, second object. This is what I have working.

Now I am trying to expand this by having the user hold the ray over the object for a protracted period of time before the material is taking off object 1 and placed on object 2. And I'm having some issues.

When my timers gets close to the allotted time, my ray seems to stop hitting it and the highlight (which appears when the ray touches it object) disappears. Then when I look away and back at the object, instead of resetting the time, the material instantly appears on my other object. So I think I might not be resetting my timer properly.

Infact I'm positive this is to do with my timer as even when my ray isn't hitting anything, it seems to trigger my change material event.

Could someone take a look at my code and tell me?

method which checks what object has been hit with a ray and casts its material onto the correct object

```
void CastRay()
{
    if(hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "Colour1" && change_material == true)
    {
        new_colour1.ChangeObjectMaterialColour(hit.collider.gameObject.renderer.material.color);

        var colums = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("column");
        foreach( GameObject c in colums)
        c.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().materials[1].color = new_colour1.orignalMaterial;
    }
}

 void ResetTimer()
{
  start_time = Time.time;
  running_time = 0f;
  track_timer = false;

}
```

Code that cast the highlights the object my ray has hit:

```
void HighLight(GameObject nextHitObject)
{   
    // Case1: Last ray and new ray both hit objects
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject != null)
    {

        //1a: same objects, do nothing
        if(lastHitObject.tag == nextHitObject.tag)return;   
        {   //1b: different objects, swap highlight texture
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
            lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
            oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
            lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
            track_timer = true;
            return;
        }
    }

    // Case2: Last ray hit nothing, new ray hit object.
    if(lastHitObject == null && nextHitObject != null)
    {
        ResetTimer();
        lastHitObject = nextHitObject;
        oldMat = lastHitObject.renderer.material;
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = highlight_material;
        track_timer = true;


        if(spawned_amount == 0)
        {
            StatusBar();
        }
        return;
    }

    // Case3: Last ray hit something, new ray hit nothing
    if(lastHitObject != null && nextHitObject == null)
    {
        lastHitObject.renderer.material = oldMat;
        lastHitObject = null;
        track_timer = false;
        return;
    }

    else
    {
        spawned_amount = 0;
        Destroy (GameObject.FindWithTag("StatusBar"));
        change_material = false;
    }

}
```

Timer code

```
void Check(bool updateTimer)
{
    if(updateTimer)
    {
        start_time = Time.time - end_time;
        running_time += Time.deltaTime;
        if ( running_time >= end_time )
        {
            track_timer = false;
        }
    }   
    else
        end_time = Time.time;
}
```

My last method that should be set my change material bool to true once start_time is over 4 seconds.

```
void StatusBar()
{

    if(start_time >= 4)
    {

        spawned_amount = 0;
        Debug.Log("status bar function");
        change_material = true;

        Debug.Log("chaging amterial");
    }
    else
    {
        change_material = false;
        ResetTimer();
        Debug.Log("resetting timer");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try working with this timer functionality instead:

```
float? start_time;

void ResetTimer()
{
    start_time = null;
}
bool IsTimerDone()
{
    if (start_time == null)
        start_time = Time.time;
    else if ((Time.time - start_time) >= 4)
    {
        ResetTimer();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It stores your data in a single `float? start_time`. If the value is null, you aren't timing anything. If it has a value, the timer is active. To start it or check on it, you use `IsTimerDone()`: the first time it is called 4 or more seconds after it starts, it will return `true` and reset the timer.

Comment: Thanks for the response but when I ran this with debug code it came back with the time logging out in increments of 4 so 4, 8, 12 etc when I need is for it to only go between 0 and 4.

Comment: It sounds like you're continuing to call `IsTimerDone()` after it returns `true`. Check on your `lastHitObject`-related code and see how you can adjust that.